# Error importing csv file data into pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've hit a brick wall trying to cleanse an imported CSV and I was hoping someone could help please?

I've got this importing a 30000 row x68 column csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("training_dataCSV",low_memory=False)
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
ID  PP1.1   PP2.1   PP3.1   KF1.1   KF2.1   KF3.1   KF4.1   KF5.1   KF6.1   ...     BLOSUM5.1   BLOSUM6.1   BLOSUM7.1   BLOSUM8.1   BLOSUM9.1   BLOSUM10.1  MSWHIM1.1   MSWHIM2.1   MSWHIM3.1   Class
1   YMPLLGIIGLVTSFS     -0.552666667    -0.279333333    0.022666667     0.087333333     -0.366666667    0.322666667     -0.504  0.036666667     -0.546  ...     -0.270666667    0.249333333     0.223333333     -0.082666667    0.004   -0.015333333    -0.482666667    0.624   -0.491333333    Negative
```

Firstly everything seems to be imported as objects, so my first task is to split the data into 3 dataframes so I can convert the first to string, second to float and third to string then recombine.

```
df1 = df_temp["ID"]
df2 = df_temp.iloc[:,1:-1].copy()
df3 = df_temp["Class"]
```

However, when converting `df1` to string using: `df1["PP1.1"] = df1["PP1.1"].astype(str)` I just get an object.

When I try to convert df2 columns to floats using: `df2 = df2.apply(pd.to_numeric)`, I get an error saying `ValueError: Unable to parse string "?" at position 7204`

If anyone knows the best way to import the data please let me know. My goal is to end up with a data frame in which the first and last columns are strings, and the middle columns are floats. If there are any blank cells, I want to replace with NaN. For the above (row 7204), I manually checked the csv file and the number is -0.159333333, but for some reason `df2['PP1.1'][7204]` gives me: `'?'`

Very weird! I've no idea what's going on with the data! If it helps, all the data is in 'General' format in the csv when opened in excel.

Thanks.

Edit: Added as requested: 
`

```
df.dtypes

ID            object
PP1.1         object
PP2.1         object
PP3.1         object
KF1.1         object
               ...  
BLOSUM10.1    object
MSWHIM1.1     object
MSWHIM2.1     object
MSWHIM3.1     object
Class         object
Length: 68, dtype: object`
```

Comment: Hi, can you share the output of: `dataframe.dtypes`? this will print all data type of your `DataFrame`

Comment: hi David, added to original post. Let me know if you have any thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it:

```
df = pd.read_csv("training_dataCSV.csv",low_memory=False)
df1 = df['ID'].astype("string")
df2 = df.iloc[:,1:-1].copy()
df3 = df['Class'].astype("string")

#convert the main blocks to float
cols = df.drop(['ID','Class'], axis = 1)
for i in cols:
    df2[i] = df2[i].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')
```

I'm a bit unsure about the `for` loop. Can someone advise if this is the correct way to convert columns in a dataframe to datatype `float` please?

One other thing I noticed was `.astype("string")` worked but `.astype(str)` didn't. Does anyone know why this is? It it simply because the str has to be in parenthesis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may specify the desired data types to the read_csv function using a dict which maps each column name contained in your ".csv" file to the desired type. For instance, if you'd like the ID to be an integer, try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("training_dataCSV", low_memory=False, dtype={'ID': int})
print(df.dtypes)
```

and the output should be something like this:

```
ID            int64
PP1.1         object
PP2.1         object
PP3.1         object
KF1.1         object
               ...  
BLOSUM10.1    object
MSWHIM1.1     object
MSWHIM2.1     object
MSWHIM3.1     object
Class         object
```

EDIT:
You will need pandas version 0.11.0 or later for the above method to work.

EDIT 2:
The way you proposed to convert seemed correct to me, except that you didn't really need to create another variable to save the converted elements to. Therefore, if you'd like to manually convert your data after reading from disk, try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
# read your data
df = pd.read_csv("training_dataCSV",low_memory=False)

# manually convert columns
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int)
# and so on...
```

By any means, I believe the first method I have suggested to be better.

EDIT 3:
As you further asked on your last comment, heres another solution, one which doesn't raise an exception on types that cannot be converted:

```py
import pandas as pd
# read your data
df = pd.read_csv("training_dataCSV",low_memory=False)

# convert column by column
df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce')
# and so on...
```

Comment: Hi there, I had a number of issues doing this. Column "ID" and "Class" were type string, and the middle columns were floats. When I tried to blanket convert it I was getting an error as it couldn't convert the string to float etc. Also, using your first method, how would you handle missing datumpoints (i.e. NaNs?). I tried this way but couldn't figure out how to handle NaNs. Thanks.

Comment: Then try my second suggestion, where you read your csv from disk as usual, then use the command "df.dropna()" and, finally, convert each column to the desired type as I have shown. This will remove the NaNs, not sure if thats what you desire.

Comment: Hi, that's what I ended up doing in the end. is there a more efficient way to convert columns 2 to 67 from object to float? In my posted answer, I used a loop. If you know of a better way let me know please.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include  a little trick which will enable you to easy convert your data while keeping the types that can't be converted. Note that this solution might create NaN's as a result of numbers it can't convert for instance. If you are dealing with machine learning, as I get the feeling by the name of your input csv file, generally you don't want NaNs anyway, unless you are building more advanced ML structures.

Comment: About your last question on more efficient method to convert columns between 2 to 67, I would go with "df.iloc[:, 2:68] = df.iloc[:, 2:68].astype(float)", tho that would only work if all data can be converted. Sadly the "pd.to_numeric(...)" method doesn't accept multidimensional dataframes, just 1D pandas series, however, you could try something like "for i in range(2, 64)" aossicated with "pd.to_numeric(...)".

Comment: @Noobcoder did you manage to achieve the results you were expecting ? If not, please let me know the pandas version you are using and, in addition, try providing more details about the dataset you are reading from.